# PHP : escape sequence for #

Tags: php

My program consist of single, double quotes and a hash function. Since `#` is a comment in PHP, I am not able to use it in my program. I have tried using the single quotes but still couldnt get it .

```
" class='inline' href='javascript:getlightboxcontent("#inline_content");' style='text-decoration:none;'>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape `#` characters in order to create a string in PHP. Inside double quoted strings, you need to escape double quotes with a `\` character. Example:

```
$string = "abc \"def\" ghi";
```

The value of `$string` in the above example will be:

```
abc "def" ghi
```

---

In your case, if your string is:

```
" class='inline' href='javascript:getlightboxcontent("#inline_content");' style='text-decoration:none;'>"
```

then you can use something like this:

```
" class='inline' href='javascript:getlightboxcontent(\"#inline_content\");' style='text-decoration:none;'>"
```

or, if you don't want to use single quotes for HTML attribute values, you could also use something like this:

```
" class=\"inline\" href=\"javascript:getlightboxcontent('#inline_content');\" style=\"text-decoration:none;\">"
```